# Why choose CGLIB proxying as the default after SpringBoot 2.0

Tags: proxy, cglib

Why choose CGLIB proxying as the default after SpringBoot 2.0 ? What are the advantages? thanks

Comment: Makes it easier to get started, that's all.

Answer (score 2):

Interface based proxying would occasionally cause hard to track down `ClassCastExceptions`. Specifically, it was possible that a `@Bean` would be replaced with a JDK proxy and then could not be injected in its original class form.

Since Spring Framework has a shaded copy of CGLIB these days, there was very little reason not to use it out-of-the-box.